# Why bin/www file doesn't have extension in express-generator?

Tags: node.js, express

I always have this doubt and I don't know why the file inside the bin folder which create a simple http server doesn't have a .js extension.

Is there a reason behind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's tradition on unix that executables don't have extension.

For example, on Linux and MacOS to list a directory you type:

```
ls
```

you don't type

```
ls.exe
```

Another example, to launch the Dropbox service on Linux you can type

```
dropbox
```

you don't type

```
dropbox.py
```

even though dropbox is just a text file containing Python code.

Unix (and also bash terminal on Windows) have a feature where if a file is marked as executable (using the `chmod` command) and the first line contains:

```
#!
```

.. then the shell (the program controlling the command line) will remove the first two characters (`#!`) and execute the rest of that first line. This is often called the shbang line (sh = shell, `!` = bang).

Therefore, if you want to develop a command-line program in node.js all you need to do is start the file with `#! /usr/bin/env node`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
//       ^
//       |
//  the 'env' command will find the correct install path of node

console.log('hello world');
```

Then use `chmod` to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x my-script.js
```

Of course, creating a program that ends in `.js` does not look "professional". For example you don't type `gulp.js` when you run gulp and you don't type `npm.js` when you run `npm`. So people follow tradition and make their executable scripts have no extension - it makes it harder for people to realise that you didn't write the program in C or assembly language.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how that works then. Things in `bin` are supposed to be executable scripts

Comment: Ah OK. I've always manually structured my express app and have never used express-generator (express didn't have a generator when I started using it unlike it's competitor back then - sails.js). If that's the case then it means that `www` is defined as the main executable in package.json. If you run `npm link` in your project it will create a command called `www` that you can call from any directory - just like any other command/program

Answer (score 1):

Because `www` file is executable.

Open a console, go to the `bin` folder, and type `./www` . The server will run.